# Using a NdefLaunchAppRecord restarts the app even if it is already open

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc

I want my Windows Phone 8 app to be opened if a NDEF message is received from another WP8 device. This works fine as long as the app is not open on the target device. The user is asked if he wants to open the app. If the app is already open the user will still be prompted if he wants to open it as if it wasn't already open. I want the message to be sent if the app is already open without WP8 displaying any alerts.

Is there a way to achieve this? This is what I have tried so far:

```
NdefLaunchAppRecord appLaunchRecord = new NdefLaunchAppRecord();
appLaunchRecord.AddPlatformAppId("WindowsPhone", launchAppString);
appLaunchRecord.Arguments = "Test";

NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage { appLaunchRecord };

var msgId = ProximityDevice.GetDefault().PublishBinaryMessage(
    "NDEF", ndefMessage.ToByteArray().AsBuffer(), MessageWrittenHandler);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on [CodePlex](https://ndef.codeplex.com/discussions/459800) on the discussion board of the NDEF library. The short answer: No, LaunchApp and URI records always prompt to open the app, even if it is already in the foreground.